# osm2po cycle routes

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I'd like to use osm2po for a little bike routing planner. Is there a way I can mark those edges that are part of some national, regional or local bike network?
It would be nice to give them a higher priority in the routing process as there are usually better for cycling than other roads..

As far as I can see, those bike networks are defined by tags and/or relations : http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Cycle_routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, setting

```
wtr.finalMask=bike
rtr.supportedRouteClazzes=bicycle
```

filters all cycleways and adds ways referenced by Bicycle-Relations.
You'll find the extra info in the meta-column of the *_4pgr-PostGIS-Table.

In order to modify costs, you'll have to overwrite the
`DefaultJoinFilter.validate(Way way)` -method.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the folowing:  wtr.finalMask = car|bike|foot|ferry
rtr.supportedRouteClazzes=bicycle  There is an meta-osm column in the *4pgr-table. Unfortunately it remains completely empty. I was using Berlin so there should be a few cycle routes...

Comment: Which version do you use? Try 5.0.0. Did you pass the params on the commandline? If so, remove blanks.

Comment: Nice! Used verion 5.0.0 now it works.. Great! One more question: Can this information be integrated in the clazz structure easily? Like a special clazz for national bike routes?

Comment: Relations cannot be handled as easy as ways. They totally differ in how to interpret them. Think of restrictions, routes or even boundaries. The only thing you can do is to overwrite some standard behavior in the osm2po-API to transport your special interpretation into the routing. The `validate()`-Method is the meeting point where all the things get to together. Here you can influence osm2po's default behavior.

Comment: Hm okay. As we are using our own routing tool it's probably going to be be less trouble to do that later on by ourselves. But thanks for your support and the great osm2po tool in general!

Comment: Interesting.. Quiet a few edges of the bike networks are actually banned for bikes according to the flags..

Comment: No, not interesting ... it's daily OSM-nuisance. Would like to know which tags are missing or even new ... or self invented or beta or whatever.